# Can't fetch photo from Postman

Tags: node.js, express, postman

```
export const readPhotoController = async(req,res) => {
    try{
        const product = await Product.findById(req.params.pid).select("photo")
        console.log(product.photo.data)
        if(product.photo.data){
            res.set("Content-type", product.photo.content)
            return res.status(200).json(product.photo.data)
        }
    } catch(err){
        console.log(err)
        res.status(500).json({
            success: false,
            message: "Error in fetching photo",
            err
        })
    }
}
```

I am trying to fetch the product photo by using Postman and the error shows that unsupported or invalid media type even I added `Content-Type: application/json` on headers in Postman. May I ask are there any suitable solutions?

Comment: First of all, make sure if the content type is correct such as `image/jpeg`, `image/png`.
And replace json() function to send() once.

Comment: It works normally now

Comment: As you mentioned before, You added `Content-Type: application/json`?

Comment: Yes it works now

Comment: my answer is help full?